# getting access to a circle's pixels

Tags: android, graphics, drawable, geometry, shapes

is there an shape or shapedrawable object i can use that(or any object), give me a circle with full control over it's pixels within the ondraw() in a view? What i'm wanting to do is place a clear circle over a bitmap then mnipulate it's pixels.

thanks mat

Answer (score 0):

The best solution here would be to create a custom view, and then rather than relying on the built-in drawing, just draw everything in its entirety in the onDraw method.  onDraw is useful for drawing extra stuff on top of a view--you can't easily get rid of what is already being drawn there.  Just subclass a view all your own, and pass in the bitmap you want to draw and go from there.  Good luck!

Comment: @ Micah Hainline ok thanks for that. I have sub-classed a view and i can draw a circle but i'm unsure on how to specify just the pixels within the circle. have you any ideas or pointers on how to do that? Thanks Mat

Comment: Good question.  You could do some simple math to determine if any given pixel was inside your circle with a simple distance from center calculation.  if sqrt(pow(x - centerX, 2) + pow(y - centerY, 2)) <= radius then it is in the circle.  If you're looking for something other than that, you'll have to be a bit more specific on what you're looking for.

Comment: @Michah Hainline Yep this sounds like more what i'm looking for. I'm new to android graphics so if you could bear with me. Eventually i'd like to have a circle on the bitmap and apply a spherize filter to the circles pixels. But for now to lessen the learning curve i'd like to maybe change the alpha value of each pixel with a slidebar. i have the slidebar in place that redraws the bitmap as you slide it, i just need to know how to specify the cirles pixels. I'm using JJIL libray and i can get the entire bitmap's data as array of ints.

Comment: i'm not sure how to find the circle's pixels in this array or if that is how i should be doing this.